# Celery Beat Task Hangs With Out Any Errors

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I have a Django app, and I'm using Celery Beat to run a task periodically. If I call the task when running Celery, it runs without errors:

`app/tasks.py`

```
...
@task(name='task1')
def func():
    # Some code

func.run()
...
```

If I then start Celery `celery -A project worker -l info`, the task runs without errors.
The issue comes when I try to run that same task with Celery Beat, imagine I have this schedule:

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'some_task': {
        'task': 'task1',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=30, hour='22')
    }
}
```

This task should run every day on `22:30`, and it does, the task starts but then hangs without logging anything, I cannot figure out the root of the issue, this is not a memory error, I have already checked that, and the task runs fine on my local machine using Celery Beat.
I have also tried to use Celery Beat Daemon, but the task keeps hanging whenever it starts. I can't figure out what is happening, any suggestions?

Comment: you might need to start celery beat too

Comment: Of course, I just mean that Celery runs the task fine, but when I try to run it with Celery Beat, the task hangs without raising any error on logs

Comment: Did you use the `task` decorator or the `app.task` decorator?

Comment: @2ps I'm using the `task` decorator from `celery.decorators`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `app.task` or `shared_task` decorator for your task.  Without an app instance, celery beat will not be calling the task with the correct task signature for the celery app to recognize.  You can find the documentation on how to write a basic task [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#basics).

Comment: I've changed it, thanks, but it still doesn't work. I'm thinking it can be because of `multithreading`. The task uses multiple threads inside and I have notice it freezes when the task reaches that part of the program, maybe that's the root of the issue, I don't know why this would work on local and not in prod. but anyway.